# How to get a dict from a DataFrame that keeps all the values if the values in the column considered as index appear multiple times?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there an optimal way to do something like this?

Lets say I have the following DataFrame:

```
    A   B
0   1   1
1   1   2
2   2   3
3   2   4
4   2   5
```

I would like to get a dictionary like this:

```py
{1: [1, 2], 2:[3, 4, 5]}
```

Keep in mind that the lists have different lengths because the value `1` appears two times and the value `2` appears three times. If I try

```py
df.set_index('A').to_dic('list')
```

Pandas only keeps the last value in B for each value in A, returning the following dict:

```py
{1:[2], 2:[5]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with `list` for `Series` and then [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
d = df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(list).to_dict()
print (d)
{1: [1, 2], 2: [3, 4, 5]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could group by `A` and the convert the values in `B` to a list:

```
result = {key: group['B'].tolist() for key, group in df.groupby('A')}
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{1: [1, 2], 2: [3, 4, 5]}
```